# Sublime Text 3 syncing error between two computers

Tags: themes, dropbox, synchronization, sublimetext3, osx-yosemite

I followed the steps by package control: https://packagecontrol.io/docs/syncing#dropbox-osx

I'm using MacOS X and dropbox, I'd like to sync an iMac and a MacBookPro. 
Followed those simple steps but it seems doesn't work, for now I've try to set up the tab size and theme, but my laptop didn't sync.

[image: Here's the screenshot of the error message]

The error says:

> Error loading colour scheme Packages/Colorsublime - Themes/1337.tmTheme: Unable to open Packages/Colorsublime - Themes/1337.tmTheme

I've tried to search the related topics, but seems no one have the same problem.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Please don't just post images of text. They cannot be searched, and users have to go to a third-party site (which may not be around forever) to see it. Instead, copy the text and paste it into your question, using the image for reference if needed.

Comment: Is Dropbox synced between the machines? Is Package Control installed on both computers?

Comment: Got it, next time I post the text for reference. Thanks for notice.

Comment: Yes, Dropbox synced between the machines. 
Yes, both of these two computers has been installed Package Control.

Comment: Can you check that files in `Dropbox/Sublime/User` are the same on the two Macs?

Comment: Is there a `Colorsublime - Themes` folder in `Dropbox/Sublime/User`? I check on my SublimeText3 installation and this folder is in `SublimeText3/Data/Cache/`, not in `SublimeText3/Package` folder. Perhaps this syncing plugin doesn't handle themes sync?

Comment: @Alex, there is no Colorsublime - Themes folder in Dropbox/Sublime/User
I decided to sync ST3 manually. Since I have only two machines.

Comment: Yes, it's the simple solution with 2 computers with the same OS.